# Deploying a scheduled webjob to Azure Webapp without Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am having a hard time piecing together the documentation on Azure webjobs, so that I can deploy a scheduled WebJob to my WebApp without using Visual Studio. In my case the code is on GitHub and I want the deployment to be fully inititated by the webhook to Azure.

The documentation mentions that I can drop .exe into: \App_Data\jobs\continuous\webjob1 of my WebApp. I have created a post-build script that does that, which works fine. It's discovered and displayed in the Azure manager. But I can't make i scheduled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following [post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/) to easily add a schedule to your WebJob.

Note that the path you are deploying the WebJob to `\App_Data\jobs\continuous\webjob1` is actually for a continuous WebJob, you need a triggered WebJob that would go in the **triggered** directory `\App_Data\jobs\triggered\webjob1`.

Then you just add the settings.job file with the **schedule** property in the form of a cron expression (with 6 fields).

For example - `{"schedule": "* 0 * * * *"}` (once an hour at 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, ...).

> Note that it requires your site to be "Always On".

Another option is to use Azure Scheduler service which you can configure from the current Azure Portal.

Comment: can i have scheduled web job for every one hour(i.e 1am,2am... ) without always on ? (My web app in shared mode)

Comment: no, it will not work as the underling site will go down and the schedule will not happen when its down.